# Where should I set generatePublisherEvidence to false in an asp.net app?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config, web-applications

To reduce the loading time [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2008/02/29/should-i-authenticode-sign-my-net-assembly.aspx) suggests we set  generatePublisherEvidence to false in the app.config for executables.

```
<configuration> 
   <runtime> 
      <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
   </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Where do I set it for web apps? The blog suggests that this does not go to the web.config. Where else should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on the same blog entry mentions to put it in aspnet.config in C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vxxxxx. That's where I put it. Could not find setting specific to one app.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should go in the machine.config of the IIS server. However it can be put in the web.config, in the `<configuration>` section - but **not** as the first element. It must go after `<configSections>`.